# Create an unknown number of "nested" variables

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to find a way to create a variable number of variables with subvariables to store data, before parsing it to sort it.

Let's go deeper: I need to store a variable number of next departures data for stops from the two directions of a variable list of transportations lines. Parsing a feed, I have each time I iterate items with a for loop one vehicle from a line with its departures at each stop in a given direction, so I don't know at start how many and which lines, stops and departures I will have.

I don't know how to create the relevant variables to be able to store all this data and then being able to iterate next departures on each stop using line, direction and stop names as keys.

Could you help me find the proper structures to use and how?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you need to model your data, but python dictionaries sound like something you can use, and you can add items to them as the needs be.

Comment: Why don't you use lists and dictionaries for this task? You can dynamically append new objects to it...

Comment: I thought of it, but I don't know how to properly organise them to make it doable. Let's say I have a "C" line with W and X stops, with two departure times each on each direction (W, outbound: 11:00, 12:00; X, outbound: 11:30, 12:30; W, inbound: 11:45, 12:45; X, inbound 12:15, 13:15) and a "B" line with Y and Z stops, with two departure times each on each direction (Y, outbound: 11:00, 12:00; Z, outbound: 11:30, 12:30; Y, inbound: 11:45, 12:45; Z, inbound 12:15, 13:15), how do I dynamically set them? I'm not at all used to deal with dynamically nesting data... hence my question.

Comment: Remember that at the time I set them, I don't know how many stops and departures I have, and if I already created the line-direction-stop object for a previous vehicle or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with simply items:

```
vehicles = ('vehicle 1', 'vehicle 2')

# Simulating 2 departures list
dep_vehicle_1 = [str(time).zfill(2)+':00' for time in range(10)]
dep_vehicle_2 = [str(time).zfill(2)+':00' for time in range(5)]

# Create a dictionary to start collecting departures times
departures_list = {}

# Filling the departures dictionary with vehicles
for vehicle in vehicles:
    departures_list[vehicle] = []
    # Output:
    # {'vehicle 1': [], 'vehicle 2': []}

# Later, to add (n) departures time, just launch the loop for each vehicle:
departures_list['vehicle 1'] += dep_vehicle_1
departures_list['vehicle 2'] += dep_vehicle_2

# If later you need to iterate over time, you can do:
for time in departures_list['vehicle 1']:
    print(time)
```

Also need to note that you can nest a dictionary into a dictionary:

```
departures_list['another_set'] = {'option1': 'value1', 'option2': 'value2'}
print(departures_list)
'''
{'vehicle 1': ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00',
 '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00'],
 'vehicle 2': ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00'],
 'another_set': {'option1': 'value1', 'option2': 'value2'}}
'''

print(departures_list['another_set'])
# {'option1': 'value1', 'option2': 'value2'}

print(departures_list['another_set']['option1'])
# value1
```

If you want to iterate over the unknown number of vehicles in your dictionary you can:

```
for key in departures_list:
    print(key, departures_list[key])
```